# HTTP requests have increased considerably since enabling continuous replication

Tags: cloudant

I have noticed that the number of HTTP requests on my Cloudant multi-tenant account have experienced a fairly big step increase, but the number of requests made by my client have remained at approximately the same level.

I have recently setup continuous replication to another multi-tenant account around the time that the step increase occurred.

**Question**: Could replication be responsible for this step increase in HTTP requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that continuous replication is the cause of this step increase.  Continuous replication does result in quite a few network calls between the source and target databases.

To verify that your continuous replication is a major contributor to your HTTP usage, you could disable your replication for a day and check that usage charts in the Cloudant dashboard show a steep drop in HTTP requests for that period.

Comment: For more information about what HTTP requests are made by the replicator and why, see this description of the replication protocol: http://dataprotocols.org/couchdb-replication/