# continous replication on multi-tenant account using too much of my http usage

Tags: cloudant

Continuous replication of a Cloudant database can result in quite a high number of HTTP requests consuming your HTTP usage.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174987/http-requests-have-increased-considerably-since-enabling-continuous-replication) for more info.

**Question:** What are the main alternative options available for replicating my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to setup is to write a small cron type service (e.g. in AWS or Bluemix) that uses the Cloudant [HTTP Replication API](http://docs.cloudant.com/guides/replication/replication.html) to create one off replications at set intervals (e.g. hourly, or whatever period the business deem acceptable).